# node red show different key values in different gauges comes from same payload

Tags: node-red, payload

my massage is:

```
object
topic: "\topic_1"
payload: "{"read":4,"write":6}"
qos: 0
retain: false
_msgid: "7bd2eaa7.ba8e04"
```

and I want to show value of read and write in different gauges. Node red

I have tried using split and switch node together but its not working

[image].

Thank You

Comment: You have to show us what you've tried so we can help you fix it. Edit the question to include details of what you've tried and how it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried split and switch nodes together but when I use split and switch node then it doesn't gives any output.